# Is it possible to use @ConstructorBinding bound immutable @ConfigurationProperties beans in an implementation of EnvironmentPostProcessor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to use **@ConstructorBinding** bound immutable **@ConfigurationProperties** beans in an implementation of **EnvironmentPostProcessor**?

I have an **EnvironmentPostProcessor** implementation:

```
@Order(LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({KeyVaultCertificatesEnvironmentProperties.class, KeyVaultCertificatesEnvironmentServerSslProperties.class})
public class KeyVaultCertificatesEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    private KeyVaultCertificatesEnvironmentProperties keyVaultProperites;
    private KeyVaultCertificatesEnvironmentServerSslProperties sslProperties;
```

This implementation must use some **@ConfigurationProperties** beans. I would like these bean to be immutable.  Here is a sketch of the beans

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix=KeyVaultCertificatesEnvironmentProperties.PREFIX)
public class KeyVaultCertificatesEnvironmentProperties {

//...
}

@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix=KeyVaultCertificatesEnvironmentServerSslProperties.PREFIX)
public class KeyVaultCertificatesEnvironmentServerSslProperties {
//...
}
```

I don't know how to make it so the two **@ConfigurationProperties** beans are available to my **EnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment** implementation.  I suspect there may be some timing issues.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to directly use any `@ConfigurationProperties` beans with an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` because the `ApplicationContext` that holds the beans is always created after the `Environment`. It is, however, possible to use the `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder` class directly if you want to create a an object from the properties that have been loaded into the `Environment` so far.

For example, you can have the following class:

```
public class Certs {

    // ... fields

    Certs(String first, String second) {
      // ...
    }   

}
```

and bind it with the following code:

```
Binder binder = Binder.get(environment);
Certs certs = binder.bind("my.certs", Certs.class).get();
```

Note that the `Certs` properties class doesn't use any `@ConfigurationProperties` or `@ConstructorBinding` annotations and it has a single constructor. For more complex setups you might need to use the `Binder` constructor that accepts a `BindConstructorProvider`.

If you're using Spring Boot 2.4 or above you might want to look into the `ConfigDataLocationResolver` and `ConfigDataLoaders` classes. These allow you to support custom imports from an `application.properties` or `application.yaml` file. The resolver provides a `ConfigDataLocationResolverContext` object with a `getBinder()` method that you can use for reading additional properties. You can read a bit about it [in this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4).

You can also look at the new `org.springframework.boot.Bootstrapper` interface that was added in Spring Boot 2.4 to help Spring Cloud solve a similar chicken-and-egg problem. There's also a [test application in the Spring Boot codebase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.4.1/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-bootstrap-registry) that might help.